Convergence in measure and almost uniform Cauchy convergence almost everywhere
I,m trying to prove the following: Let $(X, \Omega, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f,f_n: \Omega \to \mathbb{K}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be measurable functions where $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in measure to $f$ and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an almost uniform Cauchy sequence. Then, the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly almost everywhere.
I know the convergence in measure assure us that the set of points on which $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converges uniformly becomes of smaller measure as $n \to \infty$. I think that the condition of almost uniform Cauchy convergence make such set to be somehow fixed in $X$. Is this correct?

Note that convergence in measure implies that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_l})$ that converges almost uniformly to $f$. Hence, we can find $A_1$ such that $\mu(A_1)< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $(f_{n_l})\to f$ uniformly in $X\setminus A_1$. We can also find $A_2$ such that $\mu(A_2)< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy in $X\setminus A_2$.
Now, given a $\epsilon > 0$ show that $A_1 \cup A_2$ is the set that you are looking for showing almost uniform convergence.
